# How to manage admin side in Nuxt (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to protect my admin interface inside nuxt.js.

Protecting the data is easy with an authentication on the API, but i don't want any user to see my admin interface by simply modifying the client side authentication code.

I was thinking about creating a second app only for admin but is there a better way ?

Comment: Hello i'm facing the same issue. What is the best solution you've found ?